# Hibernate is not using index

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, db2, spring-data-jpa

I have been doing performance tuning of an application I have.
It is Spring based, uses hibernate 4.2.19.Final. and database is DB2

In database there is table CUSTOMER with many fields on it.
2 of which are status and surname, these 2 columns are contained in an index.

Hibernate/Spring Data repository generates the following statement and it does **NOT** use the index:

```
 select * from CUSTOMER where status=? and surname=?
```

If I do the following from any DB client tool, it will **USE** the index

```
 select * from CUSTOMER where status='LIVE' and surname='BLAAAA'
```

The main difference is that under the hood, hibernate seems to use a PreparedStatement with bind parameters. ie. (ps.setString(2, Constants.STATUS.SUSPENDED.name());)

I am using db2explain, db2top, IBM data studio to verify the index is not getting used by hibernate.

Does anybody know of a way to fix this issue? 
Or do I have to avoid hibernate/spring data in this scenaroi, and do a custom query?

Comment: I don't think Hibernate is the problem here. DB2 will decide when to use and index or not to use and index this is a function of the database server rather than a function of JPA.

Answer (score 0):

The decision to use the index or not is probably made by DB2, not Hibernate. My best guess for why it isn't using the index because the column **status has low cardinality**. In that case, it's possible that DB2 decides that a table scan might actually be faster.

[http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1309cardinal/](http://Low%20Cardinality%20Indices)

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate really does not "interfere" with indexes. When the framework executes the queries it will auto-generate the SQL from the provided and the mappings, later then this is sent directly to the database and right there, the RDMS will determine what's the "best way" to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

As the others already mentioned: Hibernated doesn't decide to use or not use an index. Your database does.

The challenge for the database is: it can tell that the index is helpful for status='LIVE' and surname='BLAAAA' but it decides that for arbitrary values the index is not helpful and it normally decides on the execution plan before binding parameters.

DB2 seems to offer a way to force it to recreate the execution plan after binding parameters. 
It actually seems to have two variants.

Either force it for all statements or specify it only for certain statements.
[Both variants are described in this detailed article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1104db2statementconcentratorreoptimization/index.html#N102CD).